# Combine columns from several files into one

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have several files with two columns : 
file 1:

```
1 100
2 103
```

file 2

```
1 200
2 203
```

and around 600 such files with two columns.

Now, I would like to combine the second column in every file of the first row in the correct sequence to get a single data file like :

```
100
200
.
.
. (600 lines)
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Are the files named in such a way that a filename globbing pattern would list them in the correct sequence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==1 {print $2}' file*
```

This prints the second column (`$2`) of the first line (`FNR==1`) for every file whose filename starts with `file`.

An alternative is to print the first line and then immediately skip to the next file (`nextfile` is a `mawk` and GNU `awk`-specific keyword):

```
awk '{print $2; nextfile}' file*
```

Answer (score 1):

Best answer has been given above. Tried with below command

```
for i in file1 file2; do awk 'NR==1{print $2}' $i; done
100
200
```

Comment: I'd suggest at least using a wildcard for the `for` loop, as the OP indicated "around 600 such files" -- so that they don't have to type out each one.  Also quote `$i` as `"$i"` when you refer to it, otherwise your solution will break on files named, for example: `file number 5`.